# Building a String of dynamic length - least consuming way?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I want to write a series of the character `-`, the amount equaling to 50% of the terminal window column size.

I already have the column size. Let's say the terminal column size is 30.
My desired end result would be a String variable containing this:

```
echo $column_width
---------------
# That is 15 x "-"
```

How should I go about building this variable? Should I loop through 0 < $column_width and concatenate a "-" for each iteration, or is there a smarter way? In case you wonder, this is just some stuff for a bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is good at this:

```
separator=$( perl -e 'print "-" x (qx(tput cols) / 2)' )
```

With the shell:

```
separator=$( printf "%*s" $(( $(tput cols) / 2 )) " " | sed 's/ /-/g' )
```

where `tput cols` is used to grab the current terminal width.